# RegEx for accessing a nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, regex-group

I have some JS objects and they each have a grandchild property called 'products'.

E.g. `ecommerce.add.products, ecommerce.remove.products, ecommerce.detail.products, ecommerce.checkout.products, ecommerce.purchase.products`

I would like to access the products array regardless of what the specific object out of the above it is.

Tried using regex:

```
var ecomProducts = ecom[('detail'|'add'|'remove'|'checkout'|'purchase')]['products'];
```

> TypeError: ecom[(((("detail" | "add") | "remove") | "checkout") | "purchase")] is undefined

```
var ecomProducts = ecom[/'detail'|'add'|'remove'|'checkout'|'purchase'/]['products'];
```

> TypeError: ecom[/'detail'|'add'|'remove'|'checkout'|'purchase'/] is undefined

How can I access the nested grandchild 'products' object regardless of the parents name?

Comment: The regex that describe the above is: /ecommerce.[add|remove|detail|checkout|purchase].products/.
But if you need to *access* - regex may not be sufficient since you have to *check* which pattern apply.

Comment: Eventually more generic way: `Object.values(ecommerce).find(item => typeof item === 'object' && item !== null && !!item.products)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply loop through the `ecom` object and check for existence of following props `detail','add','remove','checkout','purchase'` on `ecom` object,

something like this

```
let outerKey = ['detail','add','remove','checkout','purchase']
let foundProducts = outerKey.reduce((op,inp) => {
      if(ecom[inp] && ecom[inp].products && ecom[inp].products.length){
      op.push(ecom[inp].products)
      }  
     return op
},[])
```

> Tried using regex:

```
var ecomProducts = ecom[('detail'|'add'|'remove'|'checkout'|'purchase')]['products'];
```

No this is not regex this is just **logical OR**, so you always end with `ecom['checkout']['products']`

Comment: This does what I need thank you. Thanks too for the additional info on why my 'regex' was failing

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have an object like that::

```js
ecommerce = { 
   add: { products: ['add products'] },
   remove: { products: ['remove'] },
   detail: { products: ['prod details'] },
   checkout: { products: ['checkout'] },
   purchase: { products: ['purchase'] }
};

    for( var x in ecommerce )"products" in ecommerce[ x ] ? 
    console.log( ecommerce[ x ].products ) : 0;
```

You cannot pick up apples from whichever tree you happen upon - you will need to visit the trees and the branches that contain them...

The easiest and the most portable way would be to have a function that utilizes the following expression ::

```
for( var x in ecommerce )"products" in ecommerce[ x ] ? 
console.log( ecommerce[ x ].products ) : 0;
```

and run error free.